# Chrome 80 allows insecure SameSite=None cookies

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

I recently upgraded to Chrome 80 and enabled the new SameSite policy for cookies in `chrome://flags`. While developing locally, my server framework is set up to emit the authentication cookies with the `SameSite=None` attribute. For the time being I don't have SSL enabled.

Now I'm wondering, how come Chrome allows these, as, if I've understood the policy correctly, all `SameSite=None` cookies must be secure, regardless of environment?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will only be able to set `SameSite=None` with `Secure`. So, I think if you do not have SSL in your dev environment, you should not set either of these attributes.

The new behaviour comes from both:

- `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies`
- **and** `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure`

You can check if your browser is enforcing the complete behaviour on https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me

Comment: So you mean that the second flags's wording is misleading, i.e. it also blocks `SameSite=None` cookies that are not secure?